# Rspec private method can't access class instance variable?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I am testing my class' initialize method.  It calls a private method, and for some reason that method is failing.

Class (code simplified for brevity):

```
class MyClass
  @configs = {}

  def initialize(configs)
    @configs = configs
    check_configs
    create_client
  end

private 

 def check_configs
    if @configs['some_token'].nil?
      Rails.logger.git_loader.error('log message')
      raise AnError
    end
 end

end
```

The test:

```
 describe '#initialize' do
    let(:config) { my_token: '123-FakeToken' }
    let(:loader) { described_class.new(config) }
    context 'when initialized with a set of configs' do
      it { expect(loader.instance_variable_get(:@configs)).to eq(configs)}
    end
  end
```

When I put a `puts` before the `nil?` check, the token prints out nothing, though when my rake task calls the `initialize` method, it prints fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example is a bit confusing due to the various spelling errors in your attempt to generalize your problem. I created the following two files, and the specs ran just fine. Might be a naming error that you're experiencing and not an actual rspec problem.

```
# test_spec.rb

require 'rspec'
require_relative 'my_class'

describe MyClass do
  describe '#initialize' do
    let(:configs) { {some_token: '123-FakeToken'} }
    let(:loader) { described_class.new(configs) }
    context 'when initialized with a set of configs' do
      it { expect(loader.instance_variable_get(:@configs)).to eq(configs)}
    end
  end
end
```

and

```
# my_class.rb
class MyClass
  #@configs = {}

  def initialize(configs)
    @configs = configs
    check_configs
  end

  private

  def check_configs
    if @configs[:some_token].nil?
      puts "log message"
      raise 'an error'
    end
  end
end
```

---

That said, the bigger question is what are you trying to accomplish with your tests?

Testing private variables is a smell. Ideally, in the case of config variables, they will cause an effect in your instance when set. For example `MyClass.foo` will behave differently based on whether `some_token` is set or not. Testing whether the behaviour of `foo` changes with a `some_token` present or not is a high value test that you want. Instead of a low value test of whether you wrote `@configs = configs` correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Because you made your method check_configs in a private scope, you're unable to access it from the initialize method because the object you're initializing is looking for a method that is essentially hidden to the class. You either need to make the method public or rework your initialize method to not include private methods.

- note, I came back and noticed this was not clear enough.

Initialize methods are always public, therefore they cannot include any private scoping within the method. You could call a private method anywhere else within the class except the initialize method

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Classes#Private